# Clipping images in rasterio adds black pixels

Tags: python, gis

not sure if this should be here or on the GIS board.

I have large sentinel (geotiff) images that I want to clip to a smaller region of interest. My RIO is just a shapefile that contains a square made in QGIS.

I have a bunch of temporal sentinel images because I want to compute NDVI over time. So I'm taking all of my satellite images, along side an additional crop map and clipping them all to my ROI.

I am then calculating NDVI for each image.

Then with a randomly generated pixel within the geotiff's bounds, I can extract the NDVI for that pixel from all of my satellite images as well as a ground truth info from my crop map in order to train my own classifier.

I am clipping sentinel bands with the following python code:

```
b2 = rasterio.open(imagePaths['B02']) # BLUE BAND

b2Clipped, b2Transform = mask(b2, shapes, crop=True, nodata = 1, all_touched = True)

outMeta = b2.meta.copy()
outMeta.update({
    "driver": "Gtiff",
    "height": b2Clipped.shape[1],
    "width": b2Clipped.shape[2],
    "transform": b2Transform
})
b2Name = os.path.join(basePath, b2filename)
b2Out = rasterio.open(
    b2Name,
    "w",
    **outMeta
)
b2Out.write(b2Clipped)
b2Out.close()
```

I am clipping all of my bands, including B4 and B8 so NDVI can be calculated.

My issue is with the mask function from rasterio, when my satellite images are masked a bunch of 0s are added for whatever reason?

When I open the images in QGIS to see what is going on, it looks like the image has been transformed so it is flat, clipped, and then transformed back - and when transforming my image back, a bunch of new pixels are added as 0s.

The added 0s make it so sampling random pixels from my images is broken: If the sample from near the edges, the pixel values will be 0 instead of actual pictures from my image.

The added 0s also make the NDVI calculation bork itself because it is trying to divide some numbers by 0.

Is there a way to just mask my images as they are?

You can see images of my clipped area and clipping polygon here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ2Pe.jpg

Can I clip my images in python without all of these pixels being added?

Comment: It seems that adding filled = True to the mask function fixes my issue

Comment: Adding filled = True makes it so 0 nodata pixels are added to my image, but the clipped image is still larger than my mask.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too recently. Maybe try to change it before plotting by:

```
band = outmeta.read(1)

band[band == 0.0] = np.NaN
```

As indicated on raster documents, the cells with no data were filled by 0s. So I thought maybe you can choose not to show them by giving these cells NaN values. it worked for me.

But for your sampling tasks, I'm not sure.